# Duplicated form disapearing after a second

Tags: javascript, html, forms

How do I keep my duplicated forms from disapearing whenever I press the "Duplicate Form" button? The duplicated form appears for about one second then instantly disapears, how do I prevent this?

**Javascript**

```
function myFunction() {
        var elmnt = document.getElementById("formid");
        var cln = elmnt.cloneNode(true);
        document.body.appendChild(cln);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="dilemman.php" method="post" class="copy" id="formid" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    Video: <br>
    <textarea type="text" rows="1" cols="40" name="videolank"></textarea>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="input_fields_wrap">
        <button class="add_field_button">Lägg till fler svar</button>        
    </div>
     <button onclick="myFunction()">Duplicate form</button>
</form>
```

Comment: why cant we append elmnt directly instead of cln?

Comment: the button in your form will lead to a form submit event

Comment: How do I prevent this? @Ramanlfc

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the cloning button outside of your form, I'm suspecting that it triggers the submit action because the button is part of your form.

Also remember to change the ID of any new forms, as duplicate IDs will break code. I suggest adding a counter and adding this to the ID of the form every time.

```
<form action="dilemman.php" method="post" class="copy" id="formid" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    Video: <br>
    <textarea type="text" rows="1" cols="40" name="videolank"></textarea>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="input_fields_wrap">
        <button class="add_field_button">Lägg till fler svar</button>        
    </div>

</form>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Duplicate form</button>
```

and

```
var count = 0;
function myFunction() {
    var elmnt = document.getElementById("formid");
    var cln = elmnt.cloneNode(true);
    cln.id = "formid"+(++count); //add 1 to count, then append
    document.body.appendChild(cln);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

form will submit by default ,to disable the default action use `preventDefault()`

```
<button onclick="myFunction(e)">Duplicate form</button>

function myFunction(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       ... rest of code
    }
```